# Is there any way to pass ordinary function and call template function?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void display(T a){
    a += a;
    cout << "Template Function: " << a << endl;
}

template <class T1, class T2>
void display(T1 a, T2 b){
    cout << "a: " << a << endl << "b: " << b << endl;
}

void display(int x){
    cout << "Ordinary Function: " << x << endl;
}

int main(){
    display(1);  // this will call ordinary function
    display(1.2);  
    display('T');
    display(1, 2);
    display('A', 'B');
    display(2.1, 2.1);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above C++ code, on the `display(1)` function calls the *ordinary function* is called. Is there is any way that I can call *template function* instead of *ordinary function*?

Comment: `display<int>(1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for calling a *template function* is:

> `functionName<dataType>(arg1, arg2, ...);`

By default, the compiler will call the *ordinary function* of the same name, if it finds the exact match. Which is `void display(int x)` in this case. If you want to call the *template function*, instead of its *ordinary version*, you need to call exactly how it is called:

> `display<int>(1);`

Answer (score 4):

You might call it that way:

```
display<int>(1);
```